# AIX : retrieving previous command using up arrow

Tags: command-line, ksh, aix

I know about set -o vi and k and j combinations.
I want to map these to up arrow and down arrow so that I can use AIX(ksh prompt) just like bash . Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way that worked for me:
Put the following in to .profile script

```
set -o emacs
alias __A=$(print -n "\020")
alias __B=$(print -n "\016")
alias __C=$(print -n "\006")
alias __D=$(print -n "\002")
```

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to write a `trap` on the `KEYBD` signal that will process the arrow keystrokes and issue the `vi` `k` and `j` keystrokes in their place.

You can find out what characters are emitted by your arrow keys by pressing Ctrl-v then the key. You should see something like `^[[A`.

For example:

```
f () { if [[ ${.sh.edchar} == $'\033[A' ]]; then .sh.edchar="k"; fi; }
trap f KEYBD
```

Test the `.sh.edmode` variable to control whether the key is substituted in insert or command mode (its value will be `0x1b` while in insert mode and null otherwise.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, However it is not working as expected. I added these to .profile and nothing happens.

Comment: @ring bearer: At a ksh prompt in insert mode (in `vi` mode) or in emacs mode, press Ctrl-v then up-arrow. Does that give you `^[[A`? If you add `echo "HI!"` to the function, does "HI!" get output with every keypress?

Comment: No, I tried exactly that (echo "Hi") and did not see any output.

Comment: @ring bearer: If you execute the function (with the echo) from the command line, do you see "HI!"? If not, then you need to source your `.profile` or exit and restart the shell. (By the way, I assume that you did that, but I'm compelled to be thorough.)

Comment: @Dennis, thanks. However I do not see "Hi" or any previous command appear on the prompt - not sure what is wrong; 
Up arrow prints ^[[A with CTRL + V

Comment: @ring bearer: I'm sorry, I just realized that I didn't say that the keystroke represented by `^[[A` shouldn't be a literal "caret-lbracket-lbracket-A" but it should be `Esc-lbracket-A`. You can insert an escape there (how you do that will depend on what editor you use) or you can use the method in my edited answer. Sorry again!

Comment: @Dennis. trap did not work, rather, set -o emacs and a few aliases did